# ANTLR4: Consuming all remaining input until EOF

Tags: java, maven, antlr, antlr4

Using ANTLR version 4.3 here.

This grammar accepts a variety of `EOF`-delimited expressions, one at a time. The expressions start with `key` and vary in syntax thereafter. Sample accepted strings:

```
"cycle in freerun" <EOF>
"runtime <= 20m" <EOF>
"grab enabled" <EOF>
```

ANTLR merrily parses all expressions into components, the listener acts on the relevant components, life is happy. Here is a representative snippet of the grammar:

```
expr               // <-- Start rule
  : freq_p EOF
  | cycle_p EOF
  ...              // Many more, ad nauseum
  ;

freq_p  : FREQ '=' INT | FREQ '<' INT ;

cycle_p : CYCLE IN cycles ;
cycles  : cycle (',' cycle)* ;
cycle   : PHASELOCK | FREERUN ;

// Keywords
CYCLE     : 'cycle' ;
FREERUN   : 'freerun' ;
FREQ      : 'frequency' ;
IN        : 'in' ;
PHASELOCK : 'phaselock' ;

INT       : '0'..'9'+ ;
WS        : [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip ;
```

But now, I need to extend the grammar to incorporate 2 new expressions, both of which end with the acceptance of any sequence of characters at all (including Unicode) through to the `EOF`. Sample input:

```
"echo = Confirm 'interlock' is clear,\n and actuate \"frequency\" button." <EOF>
"report Process complete." <EOF>
```

I'm having great difficulty expressing the acceptance of all input to `EOF` in the grammar. The following changes lead to misery:

```
expr
  ...
  : echo_p EOF
  : report_p EOF
  ...

echo_p   : ECHO   '=' REMAINING ; // Snarfs all remaining input until EOF
report_p : REPORT     REMAINING ; // Ditto

ECHO     : 'echo' ;
REPORT   : 'report' ;

REMAINING : <WHAT_GOES_HERE?> ;  // .* messes up everything else
```

How can this be accomplished? The desired outcome is that the parse tree listener will obtain the text value such as `REMAINING().getText()`.

### Abandoned Approach: Lexer Grammar utilizing mode()

I tried writing `REMAINING` into a separate `lexer grammar` and `import`ing that from the combined grammar, but ran into https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/160 and compile-time warnings. The IntelliJ ANTLR plugin also malfunctions which is a negative impact on productivity. I learned that including a lexer grammar that uses modes is unsupported, at least in ANTLR 4.3.

```
lexer grammar Remainder;

@lexer::members {
// Needed at least until ANTLR issue #160 is fixed.
public static final int CONSUME_ALL = 123;
}

REMAINING : . -> more, mode(CONSUME_ALL) ;

mode CONSUME_ALL;

TEXT : .* ; // Consume all remaining input
```

Comment: Is it possible to "short-circuit" ANTLR i.e. in the parse tree listener? Can the listener's `enterReport_p()` method snarf the remaining character stream as a String, and then instruct ANTLR to stop (simulating or skipping directly to `EOF` ?)and indicate success?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Looking for ways to inject pseudo EOF tokens into the token stream perhaps with a token rewriter. If successful I will post answer here.

Comment: Wonderful – Please do!

Answer (score 0):

You should make `.*` nongreedy by adding `?` to it:

```
REMAINING : .*? ;
```

This will consume everything until it finds `EOF`

Have a look here:
https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Wildcard+Operator+and+Nongreedy+Subrules

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: input `report report report` is undesirably tokenized as a triple of `report` tokens: `[@0,0:5='report',<10>,1:0] [@1,7:12='report',<10>,1:7] [@2,14:19='report',<10>,1:14] [@3,21:20='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]`. 
 The desired token stream is: `report` `REMAINING` `EOF`. Tokenization problem similarly exists for `echo = echo cycle freerun frequency.
(Added the missing `ECHO` and `REPORT` tokens to the grammar extension in the question).

Comment: Also, all portions of input following either `echo =` or `report` that isn't recognized as tokens generates `line 1:10 token recognition error at: 'q'` messages, one per character or thereabouts.